# Picks the last row and fill the whole column - PHP

Tags: php

**Current Result:**
[image]

My PHP Code is picking the last date and set its priority 'Low' which is CORRECT .. but, it also fills all the rows with 'Low' which is NOT CORRECT. Where as, each row should represent their own priority values like this:
[image]

However, When I make a separate file for this same code it works perfectly:
[image]

**Here is its working code:** https://pastebin.pl/view/740c956e

**Below is the code which is not working**

```
<?php
 
$formdate = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT formdate,form_id FROM `forms`" ); 

 $currentDate = date('Y/m/d');

 while ($row = $formdate->fetch_assoc()) {
   
  $formd = $row['formdate'];

 $days7= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($formd. ' + 7 days'));
 $days14= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($formd. ' + 14 days'));


$newCurrentDate = strtotime($currentDate);
$newDays14 = strtotime($days14);
$newDays7 = strtotime($days7);


if  (($newCurrentDate < $newDays14) and ($newCurrentDate <  $newDays7  )) {


$priority = "Low";
}


elseif  (($newCurrentDate > $newDays14) and ($newCurrentDate > $newDays7  ))   {
$priority = "High";
}

elseif (($newCurrentDate > $newDays7) or ($newCurrentDate < $newDays14  ))   {

$priority = "Normal";
}

}


function priority() { 
  $GLOBALS['priority'] = $priority; 
}

?>

 <table id="" class="table table-condensed table-striped">

 <tr>
<th>Form Date</th>
<th>Form ID</th>
<th>Student ID</th>
<th>Form Type</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Option</th>


 <th></th>
 </tr>

<?php
       if($result){
         while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
           echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$rows['formdate']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$rows['form_id']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$rows['student_id']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$rows['form_type']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$priority."</td>"; //  This displays the priority value 
          echo "<td><a href=\"admin_form_view.php?form_id=$rows[form_id]\">View</a></td>";
          echo "</tr>"; 
                                            }
                                          }?>
```

Comment: You will need to work out `$priority` for each row you display, at the moment you work it out once and display that value all of the time.  So work it out just before the line `echo "<td>".$priority."</td>";` with the values from `$rows`.

Comment: Step 1: Format your code so that you (and we) can see clearly what's inside the loops and what's outside it. Step 2: Hard-code the input, so you can create a [mcve]. Step 3: Remove all the logic and output other than priority, so you're concentrating on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create function with parameter `formdate` of current row. Then check time interval and return priority label

```
<?php
        function getPriority($formdate) { 
            $formd = $row['formdate'];
            
            $days7= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($formd. ' + 7 days'));
            $days14= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($formd. ' + 14 days'));
            
            $newCurrentDate = strtotime($currentDate);
            $newDays14 = strtotime($days14);
            $newDays7 = strtotime($days7);
            
            if  (($newCurrentDate < $newDays14) and ($newCurrentDate <  $newDays7  )) {
                return "Low";
            } elseif  (($newCurrentDate > $newDays14) and ($newCurrentDate > $newDays7  ))   {
                return "High";
            } elseif (($newCurrentDate > $newDays7) or ($newCurrentDate < $newDays14  ))   {
                return "Normal";
            } 
        }?>
                   
            <?php
                   if($result){
                     while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
                       echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>".$rows['formdate']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$rows['form_id']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$rows['student_id']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$rows['form_type']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".getPriority($rows['formdate'])."</td>";
                      echo "<td><a href=\"admin_form_view.php?form_id=$rows[form_id]\">View</a></td>";
                      echo "</tr>"; 
                                                        }
                                                      }?>
```